# How do I create a class with template that does operations on two numbers

Tags: java, templates, generics, types, operators

I would like to create a generic class called "BasicInterval" that contains two private objects start_ and stop_ that would be restricted to Number and Comparable:
My goal is to add public functions that would return start > stop ?, start_  - stop_, ...

```
public class BasicInterval<T extends Number2> {
    public BasicInterval( T start, T stop ) {
        this.start_ = start;
        this.stop_ = stop;
    }

    public boolean isRev() {
        return start_.compareTo(start_,stop_) < 1;
    }

    public T width() {
        return start_.subtract(start_, stop_);
    }

    public T start_;
    public T stop_;
}
```

I extended the generic class Number into Number2:

```
public class Number2<T extends Number> {
    private final Calculator<T> calc_;
    public Number2(Calculator<T> calc) {
        this.calc_ = calc;
    }

    public T add(T a,T b) { return calc_.add(a,b); }
    public T subtract(T a,T b) { return calc_.subtract(a,b); }
    public T multiply(T a,T b) { return calc_.multiply(a,b); }
    public T divide(T a,T b) { return calc_.divide(a,b); }
    public Integer compareTo(T a,T b) { return calc_.compareTo(a,b); }

    public interface Calculator<T extends Number> {
        public T add(T a, T b);
        public T subtract(T a, T b);
        public T multiply(T a, T b);
        public T divide(T a, T b);
        public Integer compareTo(T a, T b);
    }

    public static class DoubleCalc implements Calculator<Double> {
        public final static DoubleCalc INSTANCE = new DoubleCalc();
        private DoubleCalc(){}
        public Double add(Double a,Double b) { return a + b; }
        public Double subtract(Double a,Double b) { return a - b; }
        public Double multiply(Double a,Double b) { return a * b; }
        public Double divide(Double a,Double b) { return a / b; }
        public Integer compareTo(Double a,Double b) { return a.compareTo(b); }
    }

    public static class FloatCalc implements Calculator<Float> {
        public final static FloatCalc INSTANCE = new FloatCalc();
        private FloatCalc(){}
        public Float add(Float a,Float b) { return a + b; }
        public Float subtract(Float a,Float b) { return a - b; }
        public Float multiply(Float a,Float b) { return a * b; }
        public Float divide(Float a,Float b) { return a / b; }
        public Integer compareTo(Float a,Float b) { return a.compareTo(b); }
    }

    public static class IntCalc implements Calculator<Integer> {
        public final static IntCalc INSTANCE = new IntCalc();
        private IntCalc(){}
        public Integer add(Integer a,Integer b) { return a + b; }
        public Integer subtract(Integer a,Integer b) { return a - b; }
        public Integer multiply(Integer a,Integer b) { return a * b; }
        public Integer divide(Integer a,Integer b) { return a / b; }
        public Integer compareTo(Integer a,Integer b) { return a.compareTo(b); }
    }
}
```

The class Number2 compiles, but I do not manage to make use of Number2 inside BasicInterval. Can someone advise me on that matter?

Thanks.

Comment: What does "I do not manage to make use of Number2 inside BasicInterval" mean? What use are you trying to make, what happens, and what were you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to use 2 type parameters for your `BasicInterval` class. One type parameter would have `Number` have upper bound, and use that type parameter for `Number2` type argument.

```
class BasicInterval<T extends Number, S extends Number2<T>> {
    public BasicInterval(S num, T start, T stop) {
        this.num = num;
        this.start_ = start;
        this.stop_ = stop;
    }

    public boolean isRev() {
        return num.compareTo(start_, stop_) < 1;
    }

    public T width() {
        return num.subtract(start_, stop_);
    }

    public S num;
    public T start_;
    public T stop_;
}
```

`T extends Number2` wouldn't work, because `Number2` is a raw type. You need to give a type argument. So, you can make it: `S extends Number2<T>`. But `T` should be defined first, that is where first type parameter is used. This makes your class as:

```
class BasicInterval<T, S extends Number2<T>>
```

But, `Number2<T>` won't work, as `T` should have an upper bound of `Number`, as per the class declaration. So, move ahead, and give bound to `T`:

```
class BasicInterval<T extends Number, S extends Number2<T>>
```

Also, as you notice, you also need to pass the `Number2` instance you want to use to `BasicInterval` constructor. So, basically you've that `Number2` instance - `num`, operating over 2 `Number` instances - `start_` and `stop_`.

Comment: Thanks Jain,
After implementing your suggestions I got less errors, but still twice the same in the return line of the public functions:

incompatible types: S cannot be converted to T where S,T are type-variables:
S extends Number2<T> declared in class BasicInterval
T extends Number declared in class BasicInterval

Comment: @ArnaudHuck How are you using the methods? And what is the error?

Comment: @ArnaudHuck Change the return type of methods to `S`.

Comment: I have changed to return type of the function width() to S.Both isRev() and width() return the same error, given by NetBeans during the edition and when I try to build it: "error: method compareTo in class Number2<T#2> cannot be applied to given types; required: T#1, T#1 found S, S reason: Actual argument cannot be converted to T by method invocation conversion

Comment: @ArnaudHuck Ah! Minor issue. Updated the answer. Try that out, it should work.